# Do I need to grasp the Typescript nettle?

Tags: angular

Just getting into angular2 via the quickstart tutorial. The second chapter currently obliges me to switch to typescript, and the new concepts in typescript are polluting my bandwidth for new concepts in angular2. Do I have to grasp this nettle now? How far can I go in Angular2 with plain old javascript? Typescript angular2 apps will be transpiled for execution. Does this mean I'll be debugging against code I didn't write?

Comment: Take a look at [Ben Nadel's blog](http://www.bennadel.com/), all examples and code there are in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use TypeScript. Angular2 is heading in a direction to support development of large applications and there types are a big advantage.

TypeScript is also used to develop Angular2 itself, therefore docs and examples are usually first available for TypeScript before they become available in other languages. They are working on providing more docs for JS.

Build tools generate source maps and allow to debug the source language (I guess there will be some cases where you need to debug the output directly)